# "over someone's house" vs. "over at/to someone's house"

Tags: idioms, american-english

I'm curious about this because it seems like I've heard both versions but am not completely sure. This is in reference to American English (I'm in the US).

Which is correct/incorrect?

- We were invited over their house.
- I slept over their house.
- I went over their house.
- She was over his house.

vs.

- We were invited over **to** their house.
- I slept over **at** their house.
- I went over **to** their house.
- She was over **at** his house.

In other words, is it ever correct to omit a preposition when using the phrase "over someone's house."

Comment: The first set is just slang or a sort of shorthand; also common in AAE but not with *their,* I'd say.

Answer (score 2):

The second group is probably what you want.

You could say the first group, but the meaning is different.  For example: "I went over his house" could be true if I was traveling in a hot-air balloon and his house was below my flight path.

Comment: Okay, so the following is wrong? "Why does a guy ask you to come over his house?" - https://www.quora.com/Why-does-a-guy-ask-you-to-come-over-his-house Or: " casually dating a guy, he wants me to come over his house to get it on" - https://www.quora.com/Okay-casually-dating-a-guy-he-wants-me-to-come-over-his-house-to-get-it-on-However-my-parents-are-so-strict-that-he-wants-me-to-say-Im-going-somewhere-else-and-when-they-drop-me-off-there-we-would-hop-in-his-car-and

Comment: Looks like I found the acknowledgment that "over someone's house" is sometimes used by "young people" (this was written in 2008, but I heard it when I was young in the '90s) - https://www.grammarphobia.com/blog/2008/12/come-on-a-my-house.html

Comment: @user783312 You could call those examples dialect, but there are few English language dialects in which this would be considered "correct." It would have to be a highly disfavored dialect viewed by speakers of most dialects of English as simply uneducated and ignorant.

Answer (score 2):

#### The "at" or "to" is correct English

The omission of that preposition would be slang speech. It does not serve the purpose of brevity because it would be quicker to say "We were invited to their house", i.e. drop the "over" and keep the preposition.

In fact, the "over" serves merely to indicate that the house is somewhere else from the place the conversation is being held, or the place being spoken about previously.

"Over a house" might be used in the sense of:

*Searching*

> The police went over my house in great detail, looking for clues, but came up with nothing to tie me to the murder.

*In relation to*, in space or figuratively

> The family wrangled over his house for months, each child feeling resentful that the other children wanted any part of the sale proceeds.

Comment: I don't think *slang* means that.

Comment: Yeah, thanks for confirming. I think it's also important to point out that this slang expression **does occur** (in contrast to something that doesn't occur at all in American English, not even in slang, which the 1st reply suggested).

Comment: Why did you revise your answer? Now it looks like this expression **never** occurs in American English **at all** (which is not the case as you wrote initially)!

Comment: OK I have reverted to the original.

Comment: @tchrist - Yes, but nobody wants to say *vernacular* anymore, so they don't.